# noexcept requirement of vector not upheld

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move, noexcept

Technically, noexcept specified move c'tor is requirement of vector to use move instead of copy c'tor.

I found that this is not the case with GCC 7.

```
std::vector<A> v;
v.push_back(A("555"));   //triggers move c'tor
```

The above works as long as A implements move c'tor and specifying the move c'tor as noexcept is not necessary.

I'd like to know if this is a GCC issue or is normal across compilers?
Or is it the case that I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: `noexcept` is not required to move from the argument into the vector. It's required for the vector to use move constructor when reallocating, and moving existing elements from old to new storage. In your example, the vector is empty - there are no existing elements that would need to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't require a `noexcept` move constructor for `T` in order to use it when calling `std::vector<T>::push_back(T&&)`

Here's what the standard has to say about `push_back(T&& rv)` (see [sequence.reqmts]):

> Appends a copy of `rv`. 
>   *Requires*: T shall be
>   `MoveInsertable` into [the `vector`].

`MoveInsertible` is a fancy concept that just means it's possible to construct your type with an rvalue reference*. E.g. via a move constructor, but via copy construction is not out of the equation.

I think you're mixing this up with the fact that, depending on whether the move constructor is declared `noexcept` or not, `std::vector` can make different exception guarantees. See the "Remarks" for the rvalue reference`push_back` ([vector.modifiers]):

> *Remarks*: ... If an exception is thrown other
>   than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of
>   `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown while inserting a
>   single element at the end and `T` is `CopyInsertable` or `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value`
>   is `true`, there are no effects. Otherwise, if an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a
>   non-`CopyInsertable T`, the effects are unspecified.

---

*To be more specific, whether your type is `MoveInsertible` into a `vector` or not is *allocator-dependent*. That is, for allocator `A` of your `vector`, the following must well-formed:

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, rv)
```

- `m` is an instance of your allocator `A`
- `p` is a pointer to your type (`T*`) (more accurate to say it is aligned storage that can hold a `T`)
- `rv` is our rvalue that we're attempting to insert (`T&&`)